# Unable to upload paperclip image in production (AWS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, capistrano

I seem to have an issue with my paperclip uploads in production. I have deployed with Capistrano to AWS. Here is the error I receive when attempting to upload an image for a user.

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-02 19:40:48 +0000
Processing by PagesController#home as */*
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 6.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
Started PUT "/users/19" for 98.198.30.70 at 2013-10-02 19:41:09 +0000
Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0cCRXGjztCv0vs3sxdEcv98aEKTzGcNOXumh6hYPVMU=", "user"=>{"username"=>"chicken", "email"=>"cc@cc.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000006f95f00 @original_filename="download.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\"; filename=\"download.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20131002-766-swwl63>>}, "commit"=>"Update Profile", "id"=>"19"}
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m5.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m5.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m5.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m5.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m5.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "150x150>" '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m520131002-766-12kdsu8'
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m520131002-766-12kdsu8'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m5.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m5.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m5.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m5.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m5.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "300x300>" '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m520131002-766-d8rgc4'
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m520131002-766-d8rgc4'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m5.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m5.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m5.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m5.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m5.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "100x100>" '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m520131002-766-138s58z'
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m520131002-766-138s58z'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m5.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m5.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m5.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m5.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m5.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "50x50>" '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m520131002-766-wyvzz0'
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/download20131002-766-1bap7m520131002-766-wyvzz0'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3695ms

Errno::EEXIST (File exists - /home/app/xxx.com/current/public/system):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:94:in `update'
```

This is the image link generated by the view:

```
<img alt="10-m" src="/system/styles/dimages/000/000/519/original/10-m.jpg?1379454321">
```

However, when I try to browse to this directory in my app I cannot. Perhaps it's a permissions problem?  **The folder name for system appears in red**

```
app@mothership:~/xxx.com/current/public$ ls
403.html  404.html  422.html  500.html  assets  favicon.ico  robots.txt  system
app@mothership:~/xxx.com/current/public$ cd system
-bash: cd: system: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What does `ls -l system` show? What does the rails log show for the 500 error?

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 app staff 42 Oct  2 20:09 system -> /home/app/xxx.com/shared/system

Comment: Oops, that is the production log above.. what log do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paperclip is trying to create the `/home/app/xxx.com/current/public/system` directory, but it's already there. This is likely due to an invalid symlink in your Capistrano deployment.

Check the file and take a look using `ls -l` and see if it's a symlink pointing the right location. If not, update the symlink by creating the target or changing the location.